# Javascript Replace HTML tag on a page

Tags: javascript, replace

I need a Simple script that searches a HTML for a certain code so its not displayed.

My current code only replaces the whole text.  But if a person changes 1 item, it can't find it.

Is there a way to make a Wild Card, to find text like:

```
<a href="http://www.yourdomain.com">Thesite</a>
```

...and if it finds something with

```
<*yourdomain*</a>
```

then it replaces the whole `<a href....>..</a>` with Blank?

My current code is :

```
function checkLoad(){
    if (document.readyState === "complete") {
        document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(
             '<p style="text-align:center;">My Website is <a href="http://www.redriv.com/" target="_blank">redriv</a></p>',
             ""
        );
    } else {
        setTimeout('checkLoad();', 500)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Please post the _input_ and the expected _output_.

Comment: This could be an interesting question to answer but, as written, it's too difficult to decipher the question. Please, as Vohuman says, post the input and expected output. Clarify what you're searching for (`<a>` elements with a specific domain, or text, in the `href`, or any element that contains specific text, or something else entirely?) and what should be returned when that thing is found.

Comment: @DavidThomas I disagree with those saying this question is vague.  It's quite literal and specific.  It says `<`, then a wildcard for anything, then `yourdomain`, then a wildcard for anything, then `</a>`.  Is that likely to have side effects the OP wouldn't want, if they thought about it?  Maybe.  But there's nothing non-specific about the question as written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RegEx would be the easiest solution here, something like `<a.*yourdomain.*?\/a>` should do the trick. It will remove anchor tags that contain `yourdomain` inside them (both as attributes and attribute values - you didn't specify how accurate you want it, so everything gets triggered). See it here:

```js
var html = '<a href="http://www.yourdomain.com">Thesite</a><a href="http://www.goodurlhere.com">Good URL</a><a href="http://www.anothergood.com">Good URL</a>';
var replaced = html.replace(/<a.*yourdomain.*?\/a>/, '');
document.getElementById('f').textContent = html;
document.getElementById('r').textContent = replaced;
```

```css
p {color: #777}
span {color: black}
```

```html
<p>Sample markup: <span id="f"></span></p>
<p>After RegEx: <span id="r"></span></p>
```

Used one-line sample markup on purpose so you can see it won't touch the other anchors.

---

So your full code would be:

```
function checkLoad(){
    if (document.readyState === "complete") {
        document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/<a.*yourdomain.*?\/a>/, '');
    } else {
        setTimeout('checkLoad();', 500)
    }
}
```

Comment: As a trivial example of why not to parse HTML with regexp, your solution will fail on `< a href="http://www.yourdomain.com">yourdomain</ a>`. Yes, you can fix that. But then a bug report will come in that it is not working on `<A>`. And so forth.

Comment: @torazaburo, I just specifically addressed a vague question, assuming that OP knows what HTML he's serving. It was more like giving an idea rather than building a bulletproof case that unnecessarilly covers every single scenario you can imagine.

Comment: But why should it be necessary to write extra code to bulletproof this, when there are better practices available that just work? Using regexp on `document.body.innertHTML` is like ripping down your house and rebuilding it in order to change a light bulb.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to base this just on the `href`, you can do it with a CSS rule:

```css
a[href=http://www.yourdomain.com] { display: none; }
```

To find any `href` containing `'yourdomain'`, then use `*=`:

```css
a[href*=yourdomain] { display: none; }
```

If you want to include a check of the anchor text as well, you need JS:

```javascript
function array(a) { return Array.prototype.slice.call(a); }
function check(a) { return /yourdomain/.test(a.textContent); }
function hide (a) { a.style.display = 'none'; }

var selector = 'a[href*=yourdomain]';
var anchors  = array(document.getQuerySelector(selector));

anchors . filter(check) . forEach(hide);
```

No, don't use regexp for this or any other HTML manipulation.